# Merging duplicate lists and deleting a field in each list depending on the value in Python

Tags: python

I am still a beginner in Python. I have a tuple to be filtered, merged and sorted.
The tuple looks like this:

```
        id, ts,val            
tup = [(213,5,10.0),
       (214,5,20.0),
       (215,5,30.0),
       (313,5,60.0),
       (314,5,70.0),
       (315,5,80.0),
       (213,10,11.0),
       (214,10,21.0),
       (215,10,31.0),
       (313,10,61.0),
       (314,10,71.0),
       (315,10,81.0),
       (315,15,12.0),
       (314,15,22.0),
       (215,15,32.0),
       (313,15,62.0),
       (214,15,72.0),
       (213,15,82.0]  and so on
```

Description about the list: The first column(id)can have only these 6 values 213,214,215,313,314,315 but in any different order. The second column(ts) will have same values for every 6 rows. Third column(val) will have some random floating point values

Now my final result should be something like this:

```
result = [(5,10.0,20.0,30.0,60.0,70.0,80.0),
          (10,11.0,21.0,31.0,61.0,71.0,81.0),
          (15,82.0,72.0,32.0,62.0,22.0,12.0)]
```

That is the first column in each row is to be deleted. There should be only one unique row for each unique value in the second column. so the order of each result row should be:

```
(ts,val corresponding to id 213,val corresponding to 214, corresponding to id 215,val corresponding to 313,corresponding to id 314,val corresponding to 315)
```

Note : I am restricted to use only the standard python libraries. So panda, numpy cannot be used.

I tried a lot of possibilities but couldnt solve it. Please help me do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us your best effort maybe we could find the problem with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a slight change to your code you can fix it. If you change `i[1] in ssd[cnt]` to `i[1] == ssd[cnt][0]` your code may work. Also in `else` part you should add another list to `ssd` because you are creating another set of data. Also if the data should come according to their id's you should sort them by `(ts,id)`. After applying the changes:

```
tup.sort( key = lambda x: (x[1],x[0]) )
ssd = [[]]
cnt = 0
ssd[0].append(tup[0][1])
for i in tup:
    if i[1] == ssd[cnt][0]:
        ssd[cnt].append(i[2])
    else:
        cnt = cnt + 1
        ssd.append([])
        ssd[cnt].append(i[1])
        ssd[cnt].append(i[2])
```

Output

```
[[5, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0],
[10, 11.0, 21.0, 31.0, 61.0, 71.0, 81.0],
[15, 82.0, 72.0, 32.0, 62.0, 22.0, 12.0]]
```

Comment: Hello. Is it possible to somehow rearrange the result order like the one i have posted. Because the first row values might change their order and accordingly the result order has to be rearranged

Comment: You mean the result should be sorted by `id` ? please add an example of this situation to your question also add the expected result.

Comment: I have already added the example and output. Please check the last row of the output and the corresponding input

Comment: Sort your data first like this: `tup.sort( key = lambda x: (x[1],x[0]) )` this way you can use both methods.

Comment: Thankyou very much. Worked fine

Answer (score 3):

You can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby

result=[]
for i,g in groupby(lst, lambda x:x[1]):
    group= [i]+map(lambda x:x[-1],sorted(list(g),key=lambda x:x[0]))
    result.append(tuple(group))

print result
```

Output:

```
[(5, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0), 
(10, 11.0, 21.0, 31.0, 61.0, 71.0, 81.0), 
(15, 82.0, 72.0, 32.0, 62.0, 22.0, 12.0)]
```

Comment: Hello. Is it possible to somehow rearrange the result order like the one i have posted. Because the first row values might change their order and accordingly the result order has to be rearranged

Comment: No. The order of the result depends on the value of the first row value in the tup. So the result value would be ts followed by values corresponding to id 213,214,215,313,314,315 in this order. Please check the last row of the output in the post so that you can understand it better

Comment: Thankyou very much. Working fine

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vanilla python solution, although I do think that using groupby is more pythonic. This does have the disadvantage that it has to build the dicts in memory, so it won't scale to a large tup list.

This does, however, obey the ordering requirement.

```
from collections import defaultdict

tup = ...

tup_dict = defaultdict(dict)

for id, ts, val in tup:
    print id, ts, val
    tup_dict[ts][id] = val

for tup_key in sorted(tup_dict):
    id_dict = tup_dict[tup_key]
    print tuple([tup_key] + [ id_dict[id_key] for id_key in sorted(id_dict)])
```

Answer (score 0):

We want to iterate on a `sorted` instance of your `tup`, unpacking the items as we go, but first we need an auxiliary variable to store the keys and a variable to store our results

```
keys, res = [], []
for t0, t1, t2 in sorted(tup, key=lambda x:(x[1],x[0])):
```

the `key` argument is a `lambda function that instructs the`sorted` function to sort on the second and the first item of each element in the individual tuple --- so here we have the body of the loop

```
    if t1 not in keys:
        keys.append[t1]
        res.append([t1])
```

that is, if the second integer in the tuple was not already processed, we have to memorize the fact that it's being processed and we want to add a new list in our result variable, that starts with the value of the second integer

To finish the operation on an individual tuple, we are sure that there is a list in `res` that starts with `t1`, indexing the aux variable we know the index of that list and so we can append the float to it...

```
    i = keys.index(t1)
    res[i].append(t2)
```

---

To have all of that in short

```
keys, res = [], []
for t0, t1, t2 in sorted(tup, key=lambda x:(x[1],x[0])):
    if t1 not in keys:
        keys.append[t1]
        res.append([t1])
    i = keys.index(t1)
    res[i].append(t2)
```

Now, in `res` you have a list of lists, if you really need a list of tuples you can convert with a list comprehension

```
res = [tuple(elt) for elt in res]
```

Answer (score 0):

adding to the answer of @Ahsanul Haque he also need it in order so instead of `list(g)` do `sorted(g,key=lambda y:y[0])` you can also do the use tuple from the start

```
for i,g in groupby(tup,lambda x:x[1]):
    gro = (i,) + tuple(map(lambda x:x[-1],sorted(g,key=lambda y:y[0])))
    resul.append(gro)
```